# Asterisk IVR After Hangup

Tags: asterisk, pbx, freepbx, elastix

I want to redirect caller to an IVR after dialed number's hangup. I made research and found something called `deadAGI` but I couldn't make it work. You can find my `extensions_custom.conf` file below.

```
[from-internal-custom]
exten => 80,1,AGI(custom/agi.php)
exten => 80,2,MixMonitor(${FILE}.WAV)
exten => 80,3,Dial(SIP/custom/${NUMBER})
exten => 80,4,Hangup()
exten => h,1,deadAGI(custom/finish)
```

My AGI files are correct, I'm sure that. I just need to run after hangup command correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

The "core show application Dial" states:

```
    g: Proceed with dialplan execution at the next priority in the current
extension if the destination channel hangs up.
```

So change your code to:

```
[from-internal-custom]
exten => 80,1,AGI(custom/agi.php)
exten => 80,2,MixMonitor(${FILE}.WAV)
exten => 80,3,Dial(SIP/custom/${NUMBER},,g)
exten => 80,4,deadAGI(custom/finish)
exten => 80,5,Hangup()
```

If you want to run your script no metter the caller or callee hangs up:

```
e: Execute the 'h' extension for peer after the call ends
```

So:

```
[from-internal-custom]
exten => 80,1,AGI(custom/agi.php)
exten => 80,2,MixMonitor(${FILE}.WAV)
exten => 80,3,Dial(SIP/custom/${NUMBER},,ge)
exten => 80,4,deadAGI(custom/finish)
exten => 80,5,Hangup()
exten => h,1,deadAGI(custom/finish)
```

Your idea was almost OK. 'h' is an *extension*, not a *priority*.

Comment: I tried this one but not exactly what I need. If callee hangs up, caller is staying on line but AGI not working.